# Implications from the information of convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I am working on Growth-fragmentation equation. I have some problem with convergence. So, I posted my question on this forum.

I have proved that when $n(t,x)$ tends asymptotically to a stationary profile $N(x)$ times a time exponential $e^{\lambda t}$.
On the other hand, if $n(t,x)$ can't be written of the following form
$$n(t,x) =f(t) \Phi(xg(t))$$

where $f, g$ are continuously derivable functions form $\mathbb{R}^+$ to itself and $\Phi$ in $L^1((1+x)dx)$.

Can we conclude that $N(x)$ can not be in $L^1((1+x)dx)$?
Any help is appreciated.